# how to efficiently shorten javascript code DOM selector

Tags: javascript

I'm changing the script in my project from jquery into plain js.. currently I'm doing it like this

jquery script (original)

```
$('.class1').show();
```

into vanilla javascript

```
const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.class1');
elems.forEach(elem => {
  elem.style.display = 'inline-block';
});
```

is there a more efficient and/or elegant way (but still easily understood and readable) to do this in vanilla javascript?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.class1').forEach(e=>e.style.display='inline-block');` that's as short as I can get it

Comment: It depends on what `.class1` is -- an `<img>`, `<a>`, `<input>`, etc. There are alternate interfaces you could use but it is specific to what type of element(s) (aka `tagName`) you are targeting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without changing anything else, the best you could probably do is

```
for (const elm of document.querySelectorAll('.class1'))  {
  elem.style.display = 'inline-block';
}
```

Another possibility that one might prefer would be to toggle a class on a parent element and use CSS rules so that `.class1` descendants get `display: inline-block` when that parent class is active, eg

```
parent.classList.add('show-children');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also create a mini-jquery drop in replacement :p

You add enough methods, you could get away with not needing to change all your jquery at once :p

```js
const $ = (selector, root=document) => Object.assign({selected: root.querySelectorAll(selector)}, {
    show() { this.selected.forEach(e=>e.style.display='inline-block'); return this; },
    hide() { this.selected.forEach(e=>e.style.display='none'); return this; }
});
setTimeout(() => { // timeout for dramatic effect :p
  $('.class1').show();
}, 1000);
```

```css
.class1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">Hidden 1</div>
<div class="class1">Hidden 2</div>
```